# Unable to switch users in 13.10

Tags: 13.10, switch-user

Since I upgraded to ubuntu 13.10 (from 13.04), it's not always possible to switch users:
a black screen and an arrow are displayed when an attempt is made to switch from a logged-in account to another one.

My desktop is Unity. I haven't installed another one.
Display manager is lightdm.

The system does not freeze, it's possible to escape by going into a console with Ctrl-alt-F1
and kill the current session to return to the login screen. Still, it's annoying.

I have tried rebooting after removing .Xauthority files, including /var/lib/lightdm/.Xauthority,
but the problem comes back after a day or two.

Do you have any idea what's going on ?

Answer (score 2):

I struggled with this problem since upgrading to 13.10 in October. I believe I've finally solved it by upgrading to the development version of `lightdm` (1.9.7). https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lightdm/1.9.7-0ubuntu2/+build/5582036

To determine if `lightdm` is the source of your problem you could try replacing `lightdm` with `gdm`. If things go smoothly with `gdm` then continue with `gdm` or try the dev version of `lightdm`.

Comment: Thanks for this. I am trying out gdm, it seems to go fine.

Comment: The tip of trying out another desktop environment to isolate the problem is useful

Answer (score 0):

I have this issue in 12.04.4; but there's no need for me to kill the session.

So, when I Ctrl-Alt-F[number of session running I want to switch into], I get the black screen and frozen mouse pointer; but all I do is simply 'blindly' enter my password (for that session I'm wanting in to) (I just type in the password and then press carriage-return/Enter) and the session I want pops up and off I go. You might like to try that.

I've noticed that, sometimes, if my computer is busy and, thus, slow to respond, the switch-user/log-into-current-session box **does**, **briefly**, appear before being blacked out (the blacking out is the screensaver, I think); so, just imagine the dialogue widget (box) is on the screen—by default, the text cursor is in the password box; tabbing switches focus to (takes you to) the switch-user button; tabbing again switches focus to the log-in-to-current-session-you're-coming-from; tabbing again switches focus back to the text-entry box (shift-tabbing does the above but in reverse).

(The black-screen issue also occurs when I launch the 'Switch User Account...' facility; but, this time, if I move the mouse, the box appears.)

As I said, I think it's a screensaver issue; the running sessions, other than the one one is in, get locked, after all.

Comment: Blindly typing the password does not seem to do the trick at my end.

Comment: You may well be right to point to gnome-screensaver: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-screensaver/+bug/1259940

Comment: Downgraded gnome-screensaver to 3.6.1-0ubuntu6: problem **not** solved